# ImportError: cannot import name murmurhash3_32

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the sklearn.qda package in python. I have installed it successfully but when Itry to import it I get the error message below. Can anybody tell me what should I do to fix this?

```
In [3]: from sklearn.qda import QDA
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7d7abf937d66> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.qda import QDA

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/qda.py in <module>()
     12 
     13 from .base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
---> 14 from .utils.fixes import unique
     15 from .utils import check_arrays, array2d
     16 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>()
      7 import warnings
      8 
----> 9 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
     10 from .validation import (as_float_array, check_arrays, safe_asarray,
     11                          assert_all_finite, array2d, atleast2d_or_csc,

ImportError: cannot import name murmurhash3_32
```

Comment: how did you install it?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I run:

```
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
```

and now everything is working fine

Comment: Watch out, `sudo` shouldn't be needed in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

I started a new shell and this problem went away

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar situation of getting mumurhash error while installing sklearn.preprocessing library.

I upgraded numpy version from **1.13** to **1.15**

using

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

After this, I was able to import the sklearn library.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by upgrading `murmurhash` to 1.0.5.

Comment: seems more like a comment

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, so there are mainly two solutions

1. Either run it in administrator mode and install all the libraries and run in admin mode. Something that I would not recommend
2. Use virtualenv to install the libraries again and run your command in the virtualenv. This worked for me.

Hope this helps