# how to correct ImportError: cannot import name 'murmurhash3_32'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I installed scikit-learn library in python using the command

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

When I am trying to import the library or it's module like

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

or simply `import sklearn`

I am getting the error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-73edc048c06b> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

c:\users\ajain9\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
    132 else:
    133     from . import __check_build
--> 134     from .base import clone
    135     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error
    136 

c:\users\ajain9\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
     11 from scipy import sparse
     12 from .externals import six
---> 13 from .utils.fixes import signature
     14 from . import __version__
     15 

c:\users\ajain9\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
      7 import warnings
      8 
----> 9 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
     10 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     11                          assert_all_finite,

ImportError: cannot import name 'murmurhash3_32'
```

Any reason this error might be happening?

> I am using Python version 3.6.3  Numpy v 1.13.3 pandas v 0.21.0
>
> I am using windows

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005797/importerror-cannot-import-name-murmurhash3-32#25770827

Comment: none of the solutions have worked for me.

Comment: @L-- , I ran my shell in administrator mode, and the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try using virutalenv and install all the libraries required there, it worked for me.